# Jquery UI Draggable Helper function not creating new element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the element of the item I'm dragging using the helper functionality  I have the following example (which is not working):  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uxfnc/)

The following code seems to work:

```
$('#original').draggable();
$('#clone').draggable({helper: 'clone' });
```

But if I change "clone" to the following:

```
$('#clone').draggable({helper: function(e,ui) { return $(ui).clone().html("<p>clone</p>"); }});
```

It's having issues.

Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want to use clone and change the text of it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I want to completely change the element when I start dragging

Comment: Your first example works fine for me.

Comment: @Paul check it out http://jsfiddle.net/Uxfnc/2/ you need to use drag/stop events to change a clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/Uxfnc/1/

Update:

```
$('#original').draggable();
$('#clone').draggable({
    helper: function (e, ui) {
        return $(this).clone(true).html("<p>clone</p>"); //Replaced $(ui) with $(this)
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the cloning is working but why it disapear when drop.?